# How to transfer data from one form to another form using event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am creating Windows Forms Application believe to be called a singleton program design.
This is using a main form with differents options for the user to select.
These options in turn all have their corresponding forms with unique functions attached.
When the main form executes and the user select an option, the option form is then hidden
away from the user (as oppose to close) until its selected again.  Note.. ITS NOT CLOSED.

I have a form with a richtext box and after checking contents validity, I want to send that data to another form thats got a listview box... basically updating the listview box on the other form.

All of the examples I have seen creates new instances of forms which is not ideal in my case....(as my forms are already open)

This is what I have got so far....

```
public delegate void EventDelegate(Object sender, EventArgs e);

public event EventDelegate MessageForListView;

if (status == 0)
{               
  value = value.ToLower();
  using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
  {
      sw.WriteLine(value + " " + datestamp);
      MessageBox.Show(value.ToString() + " is now registered....... ");

     /// message event required here to pass back value and datestamp to the form holding the ListViewBox

      MessageForListViewEvent += NewDriverForm_MessageForListViewEvent;

      ReSetInput();
  }
}


private void NewDriverForm_MessageForListViewEvent(object sender, EventArgs e){

 /// how do I write the data into the ListViewBox or call the reload procedure again.

}
```

`NewDriverForm` had got the data and I want to send it to `viewRegisterForm` which has a listview box. The code posted resides in the `NewDriverForm`

Thanks in advance ...really appreciate the help

Comment: it is for me not exactly clear where the data resides and where it has to be send to. Which for has the event? and which form will register to it? You should consider to make your event like this: `public EventHandler<DateTime> MessageForListView;` and pass the timestamp into the call. This way you can extract this information in the registered event method: `public void NewDriverForm_MessageForListViewEvent(object sender, DateTime timeStamp)`

Comment: Thanks for your help,,NewDriverForm had got the data and I want to send it to viewRegisterForm which has a listview box. The code posted resides in the NewDriverForm

Comment: If only one instance of the form type is allowed and is never allowed to close then it becomes simple, all you need is a `public static` variable to store the instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a static event in `NewDriverForm` and specify the data type that you want to send:

```
public static EventHandler<TypeOfDataToBeSend> MessageForListView;
```

and pass the data into the call:

```
MessageForListView?.Invoke(this, objectOfYourDataType);
```

Now register this event in `viewRegisterForm` and extract this information in the registered event method:

```
NewDriverForm.MessageForListView += NewDriverForm_MessageForListViewEvent;


public void NewDriverForm_MessageForListViewEvent(object sender, TypeOfDataToBeSend objectOfYourDataType)
{
      // use here the objectOfYourDataType
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... I am not after the datetime. I am trying to get the data from the richtext box to the listview on the other form

Comment: @Ronald what type is the data that you want to send? a `string` ?

Comment: @Ronald thanks for the answers to my question. I edited my post. In this form you should be able to solve your problem